Harness for trailers
My friend is making a custom harness for trailers for a company and he said that instead of a negative wire for the LED lights the company is just tapping straight into the bed of the trailer. So for 10 LED's they don't want a negative wire going back to the battery they just want the 10 individual wires going directly into the bed of the trailer. Then he taps the main negative wire (from the battery) directly into the trailer as well.
I guess you could consider the entire trailer body to be the negative wire but it feels like this is somewhat dangerous? The only benefit is you save like a dollar on wiring. I'm just an ME and my friend is an EE so I'm assuming he knows what he's doing but I'm sort of confused, and he's not really the kind of person you want to ask questions to.

why would it be dangerous?

By using the chassis as the return path you save way more than a few dollars on wiring, plus all the labor associated with putting it in, the space the wires take up, the weight, etc. It's sometimes not as reliable as a good direct connection (e.g. the G106 box on my old Chevy) but the benefits literally outweigh the very occasional problem.

Wouldn't the chassis have a much larger resistance than a copper wire connected straight to the negative? Wouldn't that change the circuit quite alot?

Copper has 10-ish times better conductivity than steel, depending on the grade, but the cross-sectional area of your car's chassis is huge so the overall resistance is less.

The steel chassis will have a much higher resistivity than copper wiring, but it also has a much greater cross-section area, so the actual resistance from back to front of the trailer may actually lower than the resistance of a copper wire that would be used instead.

That makes sense, thanks everyone for your answers i think thats all my questions if i can close the question i will

You may accept an answer but keep the question open.

This is common practice in the automotive world.  The metal chassis serves as the negative/return wire - the battery negative terminal is connected to the vehicle chassis and engine block.
However, there should be a negative/ground wire in the connector between the trailer and towing vehicle, so you don't depend on a dirty/rusty trailer hitch to ground the trailer wiring to the vehicle.

So everything in the chassis is basically negative already? and this isn't harmful because I would need to touch the positive side of the terminal for the circuit to be complete?   And yes there is a negative/ground directly tapped into the chassis at the "front" of the harness and at the front of the trailer.

It's only 12 volts (well 13.8) so you will be fine. There might be some additional regulations if the LEDs are safety/turn/brake signals but it sounds like your friend has that under control. Or if not you get to see them taken down a peg.

@vir up to 15.4V if you keep up with car charging systems...
